# Uncaught TypeError: payuForm.submit is not a function . How to correct this error in console?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have written a form containing some input fields of which some are hidden values as shown below :

```
  <form method="POST" enctype= "multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $payuaction; ?>" name="payuForm">

  <div class="span9" style="margin-left:0;">

  <label><span style="color:#F00"> * </span>Landmark </label>
  <input type="text" id="landmark"  name="landmark" style=" background:none; border-bottom: 3px solid #b7b6b6;" class="span3" placeholder="Enter Landmark" required>
  <span class="errorval"><?php $this->validation->show_error('landmark', "Please enter your Landmark.")?></span>

  </div>

   <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash; ?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid; ?>" />

    <div class="span9" style=" margin-left:0;">
    <button id="submit" name="buysubmit" value="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="color:#FFF; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;">&nbsp;&nbsp; Pay Now&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </button>
  </div>**strong text**
   </form>
```

js:

```
   <script>
   var hash = '<?php echo $hash ?>';
   submitPayuForm();
   function submitPayuForm() {
   if(hash == '') {
   return;
   }
   var payuForm = document.forms.payuForm;
   console.log(payuForm);
   payuForm.submit();

   }
   </script>
```

When submitting the button in form, it is not going to the link specified in the action in the `form` tag. It is going to this same page containing this form. On second button click , it is directing to the action page.

In console, error is

```
 Uncaught TypeError: payuForm.submit is not a function
 at submitPayuForm
```

Can any help me on this ?

Comment: This error typically occurs if you are trying to call a function in an object, but you typed the name wrong.

Comment: wot name ?.......

Comment: `submit` is not a function!

Comment: then ? I didnt understand..

Answer (score 0):

Please read about the forms here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms

According to this, you should be able to access your form by using `doucment.forms[0].payuform`

Or even better, try `document.forms["payuform"]`

Comment: I have changed `document.forms[0].payuForm`. Now its showing error like this 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined' in console

Comment: The above method can be used to read form elements. But if you are trying to submit the form, then please use ```var myform = document.getElementById("payuForm"); myform.submit();```